# sustract the year from a date in dql and compare it

Tags: codeigniter, date, doctrine

i haven´t found this topic here, so this is my doubt.

I have to count all people who is more than 18 years. The data i have is the date where they were born (the field in my db is called born_date).

so how can i do to extract the year from that date, and then compare it to 1995?

Comment: I don't like doing people's homework for them. lol

Comment: @seangates it's not doing my homework, it's helping somebody who has been trying to do this all day long. So that comment was totally unnecessary.

Comment: I'm sorry you've been having trouble. Didn't mean to upset you. I only make the comment because you didn't provide any examples of way you've tried, not what is really happening in your use cases. The more information the better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
select * from table where year(born_date) > '$born_date_year'
```

In `CI` you may write:

```
$this->db->where('year(born_date) >', $born_date_year)->get('table_name')->result_array();
```